# VBA memory issue while assigning Range with array

Tags: excel, vba, memory, range, memory-leaks

My purpose is to assign an Excel range of cells with the values of a two dimensional array of variants.

The assignement works fine, but I face a memory problem (leak) : when I launch Excel, the process takes more or less 22 Mo of Ram. After running the following code (creating a new workbook, assigning the range, closing the workbook without saving), the process takes 33 Mo of RAM.

Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong ?

Regards,
Alexander

Here the code

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
   Dim nLines As Long
   Dim xSize As Long
   Dim j As Long
   Dim i As Long

   'Creating New Empty Workbook
   Application.Workbooks.Add
   Range("A1").Select

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   nLines = 10000
   xSize = 200

   Dim myRange As Range
   Dim myArray() As Variant

   ReDim myArray(1 To nLines, 1 To xSize)

   'Assigning some values
   For j = 1 To nLines:
       For i = 1 To xSize:
        myArray(j, i) = i * 4 / 3#
       Next i
   Next j

   Set myRange = Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.Offset(nLines - 1, xSize - 1))
   myRange .Value = myArray

   'Cleaning up
    Erase myArray
    Set myRange = Nothing

    'Closing workbook without saving
    Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: not sure what Mo is, but 11 MB of unexplained RAM when running Excel is pretty common even without VBA...

Comment: `Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong ?` You are not doing anything wrong :) 33-45 mb of ram to handle the array that you are creating is pretty normal :) Here is an interesting article on "Excel Memory Limits - Charles Williamns" which you might like to read? http://www.decisionmodels.com/memlimitsc.htm

Comment: Thanks for your answers. 11 MB (Mo in french, sorry), is not an  important leak, I agree, but the code I posted is just an example of what I have to do for very big ranges. If I set xSize=2000 instead of 200, I get a leak of 100 MB... Debugging the code line by line shows that the instruction "Set myRange = Nothing" does NOT free any memory. Any Idea ?

Comment: FWIW, I ran this code with these results in Excel 2010 32bit, Win7 64bit: worksheet open with this code added, before running macro - 31Meg, run macro up to a break on `.Close` line - 52Meg, let macro complete - 31Meg. Ie _no_ memory leak

Comment: I am running Excel 2007 32bit on Win7 32bit. The very first time I open Excel and break on the "Application.ScreenUpdating = False
" statement, 22 MB, run up to the break on .Close line 50 MB, let macro complete 34 MB. Restarting the macro a second time does not show anymore any leak, memory usage stable at 34 MB. Thanks for your help, but I'm still a little bit worried about this (not knowing what is really going on).

Comment: I understand, that the example is nothing valid and only shows how much memory Excel allocates during VBA run.  It is called memory allocation, not memory leak.  But to save memory in your project, why not filling your worksheet cells straight from the 2D j-i-loop and forget about the array at all?

Answer (score 11):

VBA isn't C, don't count on being able to control Excel's memory footprint in any way. Excel isn't great at memory management all on its own and often times the fact that you're running macros or what you're doing in those macros has little to no control on how much memory Excel decides to allocate, or whether it ever decides to free it up again.

That being said, there are a few things you can do in your code to try to reduce its mess.

1. `Range("A1").Select`

   > It's generally bad practice to select cells before operating on them in Excel. The only time you need to select a cell is if you are illustrating something to the viewer of the macro. Furthermore, this code can actually cause a problem in certain versions of excel since you just added a workbook and it there's nothing to tell excel what workbook, and what worksheet from that workbook it should be selecting. You should remove this code altogether (it doesn't impact your logic anyway).
2. `Set myRange = Range( ...`

   > This code isn't necessary since you're only performing one action with the range. You don't need to create the myRange variable at all, so you also don't have to worry about setting it to nothing, or more importantly - the fact that setting it to nothing doesn't actually accomplish anything memory-wise.
3. `ActiveCell` and `Application.ActiveWorkbook`

   > Again, these unqualified references based on calls to 'Select' and the 'ActiveWorkbook' aren't explicit, and can cause unreliable behavior, especially if the user has other spreadsheets open in the same instance of excel. You're better off storing a reference to the workbook you added in the beginning.

All in all, I would change your code to this:

```
Sub test()
    Const nLines As Long = 10000, xSize As Long = 200
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim newWorkbook As Workbook
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'Creating New Empty Workbook
    Set newWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
    
    'Assigning some values
    Dim myArray(1 To nLines, 1 To xSize) As Double
    For j = 1 To nLines:
       For i = 1 To xSize:
        myArray(j, i) = i * 4 / 3#
       Next i
    Next j
    
    With newWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(nLines - 1, xSize - 1)).Value = myArray
    End With
    
    'Closing workbook without saving
    newWorkbook.Close (False)
    
    'Cleaning up
    Erase myArray
    Set newWorkbook = Nothing
        
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

**Closing remarks:**

VBA coding lessons aside - Note that the act of opening a new workbook will ask Excel to allocate a lot of new memory - way more than creating your temporary array. This is memory that is up to excel to free or keep around, even after you close the new workbook. There will be no getting around these kinds of increases. Note that the memory footprint of Excel isn't associated with just your current workbooks, it's the entire lifetime of the instance (which supports multiple workbooks), and their backups, optimized calculation trees, undo histories, etc. It really makes no sense to compare the footprint of a newly launched instance of excel to that of one that's just done 'a bunch of stuff'.

Also note that just because Excel doesn't decide to free that memory, it doesn't make it a leak. Excel might have allocated the memory in recyclable / reusable objects that will be repopulated with whatever next workbook you decide to open. Repeatedly rerunning the code may result in a small increase in memory each time, but Excel could just as well be tracking a certain amount of instance action history.

To (anecdotally) illustrate my point, here's the memory footprint of Excel (2007) upon opening a fresh instance, and running your code once, 9 more times, and then 40 more times after that.

[image]

It's not your code's fault, the onus is not on you to worry about it, and if your business users are worried about it, they shouldn't be choosing old versions of Excel as their target development platform.

Comment: +1 for "VBA isn't C" and taskmgr screenshots.  Nicely answered!